# Use sed to delete everything after '>' and add index number plus a string?

Tags: unix, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I know this should be pretty simple to do, but I can't get it to work. My file looks like this

```
>c12345|random info goes here that I want to delete
AAAAATTTTTTTTCCCC
>c45678| more | random info|  here
GGGGGGGGGGG
```

And what I want to do is just make this far simpler so it might look like this

```
>seq1 [organism=human]
AAAAATTTTTTTTCCCC
>seq2 [organism=human]
GGGGGGGGGGGG
>seq3 [organism=human]
etc....
```

I know I can append that constant easily once I get the indexed part in there by doing:

```
sed '/^>/ s/$/\[organism-human]/g'
```

But how do I get that index built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/^>/d' filename | sed '=' | sed 's/^[0-9]*$/>seq& [organism=human]/'
```

(Thanks to NeronLeVelu for the simplification.)

Comment: proposition for last sed could be `sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,\}$/>seq& [organism=human]/'` assuming second line is always containing letter

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: You're right, my `N` is fragile and unnecessary overkill. But I think I can actually make it a little simpler than your proposal...

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
$ awk '/^>/ { $0 = ">seq" ++i " [organism=human]" } 1' file
>seq1 [organism=human]
AAAAATTTTTTTTCCCC
>seq2 [organism=human]
GGGGGGGGGGG
```

When the line begins with `>`, replace it with `seq` followed by `i` (which increases by 1 every time), then `[organism=human]`. The `1` at the end of the command is *true*, so awk performs the default action, which is to print the line.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier with a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; if (/^>/) { s/\|.*$//; print "$_ \[organism=human\]\n";} else { print "$_\n";}' filename
```